# Get the last open form

Tags: vb.net

I want to know the name of the form before the last and the last form  Name that open..

MY CODE TO CLOSE ALL

```
  For Each Form In My.Application.OpenForms
        Form.Close()
    Next
```

Comment: Did you try `Dim lastFormName = My.Application.OpenForms.Item(My.Application.OpenForms.Count - 1).Name` for the name of the last form opened? (You will need to check that `My.Application.OpenForms.Count - 1 >=0` before doing that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> form before the last and the last

Forms are added to the OpenForms collection in the order that they are opened

This means you can make a shortcut of getting the last 2 with a bit of LINQ:

```
Dim forms = My.Application.OpenForms.Reverse().Take(2).ToArray()
```

Now the last form is in `forms(0)` and the beforelast form is in `forms(1)`